# HTML Appending with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

To appending is so many way to do

**I have 3 examples :**

1. `$(".test1").append("<div>content#1</div>");`
2. `$("<div>content#2</div>").appendTo(".test2");`
3. `$("<div>", { text : "content#3" }).appendTo(".test3");`

I think

1. is easiest
2. is same...
3. is ???

Can you tell which one I should to do ? and tell me some bad thing , good thing pls...

Comment: Which ever you like, there isn't much difference and you don't need to be bothered about any performance either..

Comment: @Vega Are you sure? The third will be the fastest and the most reliable way: it does no string parsing and it can handle insecure properties and attributes.

Comment: Unless you are going to be doing this a 1000 times in a loop or something..

Comment: The 1st returns the selector and the 2nd and 3rd return the appended element.

Comment: @VisioN To me, any performance difference on the above three is negligible unless he is doing it lot of times.. which is not mentioned  in OP.

Comment: It is just my imagination or do people worry waaaay to much about this kind of thing? As long as you get it done and it's not a stupid way of doing it, just do it the way you can remember the easiest.

Comment: @ScottBrown I agree, hence my answer isn't really about which one is better, but more about what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is more of context rather than which one is better.

You'll only see performance differences in very extreme cases, not something you would notice on a typical web site.

Essentially they are of the same purpose: i.e. to append one element into another.

The difference between `.append()` and `.appendTo()` reveals itself as soon as you do method chaining.

```
var $whatIsThis = $(".test1").append("<div>content#1</div>");
```

`$whatIsThis` would remain to be `$(".test1")`.

```
var $whatIsThis = $("<div>content#1</div>").appendTo(".test1");
```

`$whatIsThis` would instead be the `<div>` you've just created.

---

As I've mentioned method chaining, here's an example

This below will hide `.test1`. Since the new `<div>` will be inside it, both will end up not visible.

```
$(".test1") // this is me
    .append("<div>content#1</div>")
    .hide(); // hide me, I'm .test1
```

This below will hide only the new `<div>` you appended into `.test1`.

`.test1` and anything else inside `.test1` should remain visible.

```
$("<div>content#1</div>") // this is me
    .appendTo(".test1")
    .hide(); // hide me, I'm the new <div>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you mention that he can chain on the first one and not on the other two.

Comment: @Vega He can chain on both methods, just on different elements, but I agree an example of chaining would be constructive.

Comment: @Vega Read please: http://api.jquery.com/append/ and http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: @Archer You are right.. and I think the answer is clear about that. Thanks.

Comment: Fine, let me add your suggestions to the answer

Comment: Examples regarding method chaining added and explained.

Answer (score 1):

all the above three codes does the same things as long as `append()` is considered.. `appendTo()` appends to later mentioned selector ..and you might notice the difference  of append() and appendTo() while chaining in terms of context

but considering the dynamically created elements , i would go for 3rd one.. coz that is cleaner and readable..

consider you need to create 5 divs or more.. creating it with method 1 and 2 would look
messy

```
 $(".test1").append("<div>content#1</div><div>aaa</div><div>sss</div>...");
```

with third method it is cleaner and readable..

```
var div1=$("<div>", { text : "content#3" });
var div2=$("<div>",...); and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

Well [append is faster than appendTo](http://quickleft.com/blog/benchmarking-append-vs-appendto) but only for large edits. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: Please add some context explaining your link and see the following article: [Are Answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)...

Answer (score 0):

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major
>   difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the
>   content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding
>   the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With
>   .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and
>   it is inserted into the target container.

As per jquery documentation

So basically both append() and appendTo() does the same thing

I would personally prefer append() rather than appendTo()